# Push notification don't open activity if screen has pin/graphical key

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Bug is present on phones with screen pin/graphical key lock. Without it works just fine.

When user taps on push notification in starts main activity and thats all, if there is no pin or graphical key it starts needed activity.

This is my GCM listener code:

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
    String id = data.getString("news_id");
    String message = data.getString("message");
    Random random = new Random();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SpecificNewsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("newsId", id);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, random.nextInt(), intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(random.nextInt(), notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

**Edit:** Looks like this problem is present only on Chinese phones (Meizu, Xiaomi).

Comment: Do the devices have a lock PIN / password?

Comment: and if the device has a lock/PIN it should ideally not open the activity

Comment: @cricket_007 on my device - yes.

Comment: @AshishSinha Oh, and is there a way to work this around ?

Comment: Okay, so since there is a security measure preventing the notification from opening the activity, then why do you consider that a bug?

Comment: Bro, you are asking to bypass android's security lock ?

Comment: @cricket_007 Never faced such thing before. And is there a way to work this around excpet from disabling lock/pin ?

Comment: Try disabling it first, then see if the activity opens. Otherwise, I would say the bug is on the older devices, not the newer ones.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok, i'll try disabling it. Thanks for advice.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok, without pin works fine. But why do other apps notifications work normal with pin or lock ?

Comment: Not sure what apps you mean, but in my experience, I've always needed to input my PIN to open anything from a notification

Comment: @cricket_007 Maybe i was not clear enough. I mean with screen pin notification just opens app on main activity and thats all, but without it - opens correct activity.

Comment: Oh. That I'm not sure about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else face this. The question was solved simply - requests to the server was moved from Activity which has fragment container to the fragment itself. Without this on Xiaomi and Meizu activity stopped on the stage of fragment transaction in the frame layout.